# Make tooltip text show like a table?

Tags: python, tkinter, tooltip

Hey guys im trying to show the text in a tooltip to look like a table in python, i tried to use | and - but it is not looking that good, you can see in the picture how it turned out.
  [image]

```
class CreateToolTip(object):
'''
create a tooltip for a given widget
'''
  def __init__(self, widget, text='widget info'):
      self.widget = widget
      self.text = text
      self.widget.bind("<Enter>", self.enter)
      self.widget.bind("<Leave>", self.close)
  def enter(self, event=None):
      x = y = 0
      x, y, cx, cy = self.widget.bbox("insert")
      x += self.widget.winfo_rootx() + 25
      y += self.widget.winfo_rooty() + 20
      # creates a toplevel window
      self.tw = tk.Toplevel(self.widget)
      # Leaves only the label and removes the app window
      self.tw.wm_overrideredirect(True)
      self.tw.wm_geometry("+%d+%d" % (x, y))
      label = tk.Label(self.tw, text=self.text, justify='left',
                   background='yellow', relief='solid', borderwidth=1,
                   font=("times", "8", "normal"))
      label.pack(ipadx=1)
  def close(self, event=None):
      if self.tw:
          self.tw.destroy()
```

here is the code to the tooltip that im using

Comment: Your indentation is broken. Please can you fix this.

Comment: It is fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see my explained code example below. Hopefully this achieves what you are looking for:

```
from tkinter import *

class App:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.labels = [] #array to store labels that we hover over
        for i in range(3):
            self.labels.append(Label(self.root, text= "Text"+str(i))) #creates labels that we hover over
            self.labels[i].pack(fill="both", expand=True) #packs labels that we hover over, needs to be fill="both" and expand=True for some maths later
            self.labels[i].bind("<Enter>", lambda *args, c=i:self.enter(c)) #bind on enter event
            self.labels[i].bind("<Leave>", lambda *args, c=i:self.leave(c)) #bind on leave event
            #for both of the above callbacks we pass in the number which corresponds to the element in the array
    def enter(self, var):
        self.var = var
        self.top = Toplevel(self.root)
        self.top.wm_overrideredirect(1) #hides the window border and title bar (among other things)
        self.top.geometry("+%d+%d" % (self.root.winfo_rootx()+self.labels[self.var].winfo_width(), self.root.winfo_rooty()+self.labels[self.var].winfo_y()))
        #the above line is for placing the toplevel window in the right place
        #we user self.root.winfo_rootx() and self.root.winfo_rooty() to get the position of the root window on our screen
        #we then use winfo_width to get the width of the widget we hovered over, and shift the toplevel window to the end of the widget
        #if you are not using fill="both" and expand=True then you will need to multiply the number by a hard coded value to get it to look "proper"
        #we also use winfo_y to get the position of the widget we hovered over relative to the window and move the toplevel window down in to positon
        for i in range(3): #we use these loops to draw the table in the tooltip
            for c in range(3):
                Label(self.top, text="Row"+str(i)+"Col"+str(c), borderwidth=1, relief="solid").grid(row=i, column=c)
    def leave(self, var):
        self.var = var
        self.top.destroy()

root = Tk()
App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

---

The below will achieve the grid layout you want instead:

```
from tkinter import *

class App:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.labels = [] #array to store labels that we hover over
        for i in range(3):
            self.labels.append(Label(self.root, text= "Text"+str(i))) #creates labels that we hover over
            self.labels[i].pack(fill="both", expand=True) #packs labels that we hover over, needs to be fill="both" and expand=True for some maths later
            self.labels[i].bind("<Enter>", lambda *args, c=i:self.enter(c)) #bind on enter event
            self.labels[i].bind("<Leave>", lambda *args, c=i:self.leave(c)) #bind on leave event
            #for both of the above callbacks we pass in the number which corresponds to the element in the array
    def enter(self, var):
        self.var = var
        self.top = Toplevel(self.root)
        self.top.wm_overrideredirect(1) #hides the window border and title bar (among other things)
        self.top.geometry("+%d+%d" % (self.root.winfo_rootx()+self.labels[self.var].winfo_width(), self.root.winfo_rooty()+self.labels[self.var].winfo_y()))
        #the above line is for placing the toplevel window in the right place
        #we user self.root.winfo_rootx() and self.root.winfo_rooty() to get the position of the root window on our screen
        #we then use winfo_width to get the width of the widget we hovered over, and shift the toplevel window to the end of the widget
        #if you are not using fill="both" and expand=True then you will need to multiply the number by a hard coded value to get it to look "proper"
        #we also use winfo_y to get the position of the widget we hovered over relative to the window and move the toplevel window down in to positon
        for i in range(4):
            Grid.rowconfigure(self.top, i, weight=1)
            for c in range(2):
                Grid.columnconfigure(self.top, c, weight=1)
                if i != 3:
                    if c == 0:
                        Label(self.top, text="Heading "+str(i), borderwidth=1, relief="solid").grid(column=i, row=c, sticky=N+S+E+W)
                    else:
                        Label(self.top, text="Col "+str(i)+", Row "+str(c), borderwidth=1, relief="solid").grid(column=i, row=c, sticky=N+S+E+W)
                else:
                    if c == 0:
                        Label(self.top, text="This is some information and stuff which is rowspanning", borderwidth=1, relief="solid", wraplength=100, justify="left").grid(column=i, row=c, sticky=N+S+E+W, rowspan=2)
    def leave(self, var):
        self.var = var
        self.top.destroy()

root = Tk()
App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: @Zitrone I placed a for loop inside of `enter()`. This for loop is what populates the contents of the `Toplevel` window. If you replace the for loop with the snippet that you want to use to draw your table that should work.

Comment: Ahh okay i get it, it is not exactly doing what i wanted but i managed to change it a bit and it looks like it could work, so thank you very much.

Comment: What is it that you wanted it to do which is different? If we can update this to be a better answer it is more useful for people in the future who have this problem.

Comment: Hey i just edited the question with a screenshot of how i wanted to look like, but i just used the tooltip that i posted and worked with String and used | and -

Comment: Is there a reason why you unaccepted this answer? Is there something I can do to improve it?

Comment: I did cause i didn't know if you saw what i exactly want because u asked me  how i wanted and i edited the question with a screenshot of what i want.

Comment: You're free to mark and unmark accepted questions as you want to. The way you want it looks like a slightly different grid config. Let me modify my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much.